# How to change the center of a 3D WPF object

Tags: wpf, 3d

I'm struggling with the best way of changing the center point of a 3D object (Model3DGroup) in WPF.

I've exported a model from SketchUp and everything is fine, but the centers got off position, causing me trouble in rotating the objects.
Now I need to make some rotations around each object own center and have no idea on how to do it...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Using Jackson Pope suggestion, I used the code below to get the center point of an object:

```
var bounds = this.My3DObject.Bounds;

var x = bounds.X + (bounds.SizeX / 2);
var y = bounds.Y + (bounds.SizeY / 2);
var z = bounds.Z + (bounds.SizeZ / 2);

var centerPoint = new Point3D(x, y, z);
```

Meanwhile I'll try find a better solution to try and move all the points to the desired offset...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate an object around it's centre you need to first translate it so that its centre is at the origin. Then rotate it (and then potentially translate it back to its original position).

Find the minimum and maximum extent of the object, calculate its centre = min + (max-min)/2. Translate by (-centreX, -centreY, -centreZ), rotate and then translate by (centreX, centreY, centreZ).

Comment: Well it seems like a possible solution. But my model has hundreds of points. How do I get the max/min extends?

Comment: Loop through each point finding the minimum and maximum in each dimension. If the object is static you can do this once at the beginning. If the object moves (but doesn't change shape) you can calculate them once and then apply the same transforms to them as to the object to get the current values.